# How to use pyparted to inspect and change Partition Table

Tags: python, linux, filesystems, partition

I would like to use pyparted (libparted python bindings) to implement a rather complex SD-Card initialization scheme.

Currently I'm using a bash script, but that is becoming rather messy.

Unfortunately I was unable to find any specification of libparted API (the API manual in parted `/doc/` directory is useless and the Doxygen comments are incomplete to say the least).

What I need to do is:

- retrieve current partitioning scheme (to be sure I'm dealing with the correct SD)
- optionally retrieve some information from there (I know how to do this).
- setup a custom partitioning scheme (>4 partitions, needs "extended")
- initialize filesystems (one `FAT32` + several `ext4`) (I am unsure if this can be done directly using `pyparted` or if I need to spawn `mkfs` instead)

Can someone suggest the right approach?

Comment: Documentation/examples requests are considered **off-topic** on Stack Overflow. We have nothing against "how to" questions, but make sure that you have **one question in the question post**, or your questions are closely related (so answering for one of them leads to answering  for others). (I am not sure whether 4 questions you have are closely related or not. If you feel that they are closely related, then you may leave them as is. But you are better to remove requests for doc/tutorial/example as they attract downvotes and/or close votes.)

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev, I rephrased the question to be more in-line with StackOverflow. What is the Right Place (if any) to ask for documentation?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the right place for documentation requrests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created some examples for pyparted covering most of this that will hopefully be merged.

In the meantime, you can see them in the pull request at:
https://github.com/dcantrell/pyparted/pull/64

BTW you should probably use GPT partition table these days too. That way you don't have to worry about primary/extended partitions, their all just partitions.

HTH